# Assigning beautifulsoup indexed values (html links and text) to a panda html DataFrame

Tags: html, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, beautifulsoup

The following code retrieves images and html links from a webpage and stores the values in a beautiful soup index. I am now using pandas in order to create an output html table for those images and links. I have managed to populate cells manually by calling on a specific index value but I can't seem to find a way add each indexed image and html text to the panda dataframe so that all the indexed values are displayed in the table. How could I do this ?

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import numpy as np
from pandas import *
import pandas as pd
pd.set_option('display.height', 1000)
pd.set_option('display.max_rows', 500)
pd.set_option('display.max_columns', 500)
pd.set_option('display.width', 1000)
pd.set_option('max_colwidth',500)
from IPython.display import HTML

urldes = "https://www.johnpyeauctions.co.uk/lot_list.asp?saleid=4729&siteid=1"

# add header
headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; Win64; x64) 
AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/54.0.2840.71 Safari/537.36'}
r = requests.get(urldes, headers=headers)
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, "lxml")

####################################

title_clean = soup.find('title')
print(title_clean)

image_links = [x['data-img'] for x in soup.find_all('a', rel='popover')]
for link in image_links:
    print(link)

image_links_0 = image_links[0]
print(image_links_0)

mytags = []
tags = soup.find_all('td', width='41%')
for tag in tags:
    image_text = tag.find('h5').text
    mytags.append(image_text)
    print(image_text)

for i in range(len(mytags)):
    mytags[i]

mytags_0 = mytags[0]

image_links_0 = image_links[0]

#df = DataFrame({'foo1' : '<a href="' + image_links_0 +'">test</a>',
df = DataFrame({'foo1' : '<img src="' + image_links_0 + '"/><p>' + mytags_0 + '</p>',
                    'foo2' : '<a href="' + image_links_0 +'">' + mytags_0 + '</a>',
                        'foo3' : mytags_0,
                            'foo4' : np.random.randn(2)})
print(df)

HTML(df.to_html('filename.html', escape=False))

print(tag)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the correct way to do it.
If you need any help with storing it and making an HTML out of it I'll be happy to provide a solution for that as well. Take care!

**Update**: Everything included, comments, scraping, writing to a file, creating tags with beautifulsoup.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

urldes = "https://www.johnpyeauctions.co.uk/lot_list.asp?saleid=4729&siteid=1"

# add header
mozila_agent = 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; Win64; x64)\
AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/54.0.2840.71 Safari/537.36'
headers = {'User-Agent': mozila_agent}
r = requests.get(urldes, headers=headers)
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, "lxml")


############################################################

the_whole_table = soup.find('table', width='97%')

datalist = []

for tr in the_whole_table.find_all('tr')[1:]:
    # you want to start from the 1st item not the 0th so [1:]
    # Because the first is the thead i.e. Lot no, Picture, Lot Title...
    index_num = tr.find('td', width='8%')
    picture_link = index_num.next_sibling.a['data-img']
    text_info = tr.find('td', width='41%')
    current_bid = tr.find('td', width='13%')
    time_left = tr.find('td', width='19%')
    datalist.append([index_num.text, picture_link,
                     text_info.text, current_bid.text, time_left.text])

    # for pic do ... print(picture_link) as for partial text only first 20
    # characters





df = ['Index Number', 'Picture', 'Informational text',
      'Current BID', 'Time Left now']

theads = BeautifulSoup('<table border="1"></table>', 'lxml')
thekeys = BeautifulSoup('<thead></thead>', 'html.parser')


for i in df:
    tag = theads.new_tag('th')
    tag.append(i)
    thekeys.thead.append(tag)

theads.table.append(thekeys)
###############################################################
# The code above will initiate a table
# after that the for loop will create and populate the first row (thead)

for i in datalist:
    thedata = BeautifulSoup('<tr></tr>', 'html.parser')
    # we loop through the data we collected
    for j in i:
        if j.startswith('https'):
            img_tag = theads.new_tag('img', src=j, height='50', width='50')
            td_tag = theads.new_tag('td')
            td_tag.append(img_tag)
            thedata.tr.append(td_tag)

        else:
            tag = theads.new_tag('td')
            tag.append(j)
            thedata.tr.append(tag)

    theads.table.append(thedata)


with open('asdf.html', 'w+') as f:
    f.write(theads.prettify())


# each of these if you print them you'll get a information that you can store
# we use `.prettify()` as we can't write a BeautifulSoup object into a file.
```

Comment: ok thx. I'll check tomorrow. What do you mean this job on upwork?

Comment: Oh, I thought I saw a similar job on Upwork. Perhaps I'm mistaken but could've sworn I did... It'll work you'll just have to replug your HTML thing but won't be hard, to store and after that show it.

Comment: sure. I see what you are doing and it makes sense. thank you for your help. Must be a coincidence as I have never heard of Upwork until now. Was it for the same website? Just curious.

Comment: Yes, Upwork is a freelancing website. 
You can either work there (do programming jobs like me) using BeautifulSoup for instance to complete a web-scraping project and similar. I'm positive that it was the same website, someone was paying X amount of money to get the same data, I thought it was you that got the job. Take care!

Comment: nope. This is something I’m doing for myself actually but let’s keep in touch as I might need your help in the future and happy to pay for your work.

Comment: I'll be happy to provide you with any kind of help or solution if needed. Here's my skype: `elvirko98` You can also find the link to my upwork profile on my StackOverflow account. I'm happy to provide you with any kind of help you need. Let me know if you have any other questions, I'll be happy to answer them.

Comment: OK so I see that we can retrieve all the relevant data with your example but I can't seem to find a way to allocate that data to a dataframe. The text data doesnt seem to be stored in any index. I would be grateful if you could elaborate the solution.